# React Context / own hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a problem with importing HiddenProvider to App.js It gives me this bug "Attempted import error: 'HiddenProvider' is not exported from './HiddenContext'. I would be very grateful if I got some help. Thanks in Advance.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
export const HiddenContext =React.createContext(false)

export const HiddenProvider = ({children}) => {
    const[hideButton, setHideButton]= React.useState(false)

    function handleClick (){
        setHideButton(true)
    }

    return(
        <HiddenContext.Provider value ={{hideButton,handleClick}}>
            {children}
        </HiddenContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import ImageComponent from './ImageComponent';
import { HiddenProvider } from './HiddenContext';
import { HiddenContext} from './HiddenContext';

function App() {
    const{ hideButton}=React.useContext(HiddenContext)
    return (
        <div className="App">  
            <Sidebar />
            <HiddenProvider>
                <ImageComponent hideButton={hideButton}   />
            </HiddenProvider>                            
        </div>
    );    
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `useContext` wrong. It has to be in a component that is inside/under the `Provider`. You could move `useContext` inside the `ImageComponent`. Or move the `Provider` into `index.js`.

see react docs: [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

Comment: but it is also in `App` 1st line. And there it will not work.

Comment: its in image Component

Comment: The problem, as @ian stated, is this line right here: `const{ hideButton}=React.useContext(HiddenContext)`.  You cannot put that line where you have it.  `App` is trying to access `HiddenContext` but `App` cannot do that.